# Tweepy exception when storing trends in a database not when printing them

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am using Python 3.6.2 and Tweepy 3.3.0.

So when I try to retrieve trends from Twitter via the Tweepy API and just print them in my console it works pretty fine like this:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(cons_tok, cons_sec)
auth.set_access_token(app_tok, app_sec)
twitter_api = tweepy.API(auth)

trends = twitter_api.trends_place(1)

for trend in trends[0]["trends"]:
    print(trend['name'])
```

It works fine and I have a list.

Now when I try to store these into a database (I choose SQLite just to try):

```
class TwitterMain():
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(cons_tok, cons_sec)
        self.auth.set_access_token(app_tok, app_sec)

        self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)
        self.conn = conn
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()

    def get_trends(self):
        trends = self.api.trends_place(1)
        trend_data = []

        for trend in trends[0]["trends"]:
            trend_tweets = []
            trend_tweets.append(trend['name'])
            tt = tweepy.Cursor(self.api.search, q = trend['name']).items(3)

            for t in tt:                
                trend_tweets.append(self.get_tweet_html(t.id))

            trend_data.append(tuple(trend_tweets))

        self.c.executemany("INSERT INTO trend_data VALUES (?,?,?,?, DATETIME('now'))", trend_data)
        self.conn.commit()

    def get_tweet_html(self, id):
        oembed = self.api.get_oembed(id=id, hide_media = True, hide_thread = True)

        tweet_html = oembed['html'].strip("\n")

        return tweet_html


if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db)        
        twit = TwitterMain(conn)
        twit.get_trends()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e.__doc__)

    finally:
        conn.close()
```

This is just the part where I store the trends data. The database is already created as well as the table.

Running this creates a Tweepy Exception, and when searching online it says it's the time limit but if so why when I just print, it works fine and not when I try to store them?

Answer (score -1):

There is no table to insert the value into, and the code that you have provided is throwing an exception:

```
self.c.executemany("INSERT INTO trend_data VALUES (?,?,?,?, DATETIME('now'))", trend_data)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: trend_data
```

Just add a line to create the table as well in the init method:

```
self.c.execute("""CREATE TABLE mytable
                 (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)""")
```

and use this to fill in the values:

```
self.c.executemany("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?,?,?,?, DATETIME('now'))", trend_data)
```

Comment: In my question, I literally said: "This is just the part where I store the trends data." Which means in order to re-create the whole scenario You just need to create a table and do your import, which obviously I did.

Comment: Refer to the SO policy on Minimum, Complete and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There is no way I could have guessed that what you wrote was intentional and not a programmer error!

Comment: Again: I said: This is **just** the part where I store the trends data. **The database is already created as well as the table**. So I said I have **created the table** and you are telling me your error is that you have to **create a table**.